# setInterval function using jquery is causing a "blink"

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Personal project using jQuery.

I'm trying to create a function that **runs on the hour for 5 seconds**. I've done this by getting the current minutes and acting when they are at '00'. (Although for testing the minutes need to be manually changed to the *next* minute, unless you want to wait an hour to see it run again.)

The function acts on 2 objects, one to add/remove a class, the other to slideUp/Down.

It works, but after the initial running, the `slideDown/Up` jQuery causes a "blink" every 5 seconds for the rest of the current minute.

I've tried setting the `setInterval` for `5000`, however that hasn't solved the issue. I'm at my wits end really.

While I am also using moment.js elsewhere. This function isn't using `moment()`. Primarily because I haven't been able to get functions working with `moment()` either.

Just head to the ....

## [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/etjrwL9d/3/)

**Remember to set the `=='00'` to the *next* minute -- sure makes testing easier** I *really* appreciate anyone waiting for this to run. I know it can be a pain to have to wait a minute to see the function at work.

If you watch the function run for 5 seconds, it *will* stop... but continue watching.. the `slideDown()` will repeat every 5 seconds until the minute is no longer `XX`.

**How can I stop this repeat??**

Thanks!

Comment: i noticed when running the code and changed accordingly the conditions on the `alarm` function.  it always calls `slideDown`. Maybe that causes the `blink` your talking.  how about adding an additional condition to it?  `if(mins == xx && !$('.projcnt').hasClass('jump'))`

Comment: `clearInterval(alarm);` doesn't do what you think it does. It's *not* clearing your interval.

Comment: @nnnnnn I wasn't certain. I was grasping at straws by that point.

Comment: Well what I'm saying is that you're using that function incorrectly - even if you don't need to clear the interval after all you should read [some doco](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) for future reference...

Comment: Thanks. RTFM comments are so helpful :) I'll be certain to read the documentation. I *did* read several instances that used that function. And in *very* similar ways. so..... Like I posted, personal project, I'm actually a designer. I don't write javascript for a living I just play with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not I sorted it a few moments after posting this.

My conditional was off, and I thought I tried everything. Guess not.

This works

```
if((mins == "29") && (secs <= '05')) {

          $('#focus').slideDown(500);
          $('.projcnt').addClass('jump');

     } else {

          $('#focus').slideUp(300);
          $('.projcnt').removeClass('jump');

     }
```

And the ...

## [working, updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/etjrwL9d/6/)

Answer (score 1):

There're two place for fix.

**1. miss usage for 'clearInterval'**
    
clearInterval parameter is The ID of the timer returned by the setInterval() method.
    reference this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp), w3c definition  for clearInterval.

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() { alarm(); }, 5000);
...
clearInterval(intervalId );
```

**2. secs >= "05" condition is wrong** 
    
change string  "05" to int 5.